# Adding CSS styles to a form_tag in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am having problem to binding with ruby form with my html form. I bind but form not showing and hidding the css style.I am using rail 4.2.3. I already the used the bootstrap gem.

```
<%= form_tag users_admin_path , :method=> :post do %>
              <%= label_tag :factory_name%>
              <%= text_field_tag :factory_name%>
              <%= label_tag :email%>
              <%= text_field_tag :email %>
              <%= label_tag :password %>
              <%= password_field_tag :password %>
           <%= submit_tag "Sign in", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
          <% end %>
```

And this is my html form code.

```
form class="form-horizontal">
 <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-2 remove-margin">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">User name</label>
              <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="">
              </div>
            </div>
           <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Email</label>
              <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Password</label>
              <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="">
              </div>
            </div>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">&nbsp;</label>
              <div class="col-sm-9">
                <div class="btm-btn text-center">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn-type">Create</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it

```
 <%= form_for @User, html: { :class => "form-horizontal"} do |f|%>

              <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-2 remove-margin">
                <div class="form-group">
                 <!-- <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">User name</label>-->
                  <%= f.label :user_name ,:class => "col-sm-3 control-label"%>
                  <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <!--<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="">-->
                    <%= f.text_field :user_name, :required => true, :class =>"form-control" %>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <!--<label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Email</label>-->
                  <%= f.label :email,:class => "col-sm-3 control-label"%>
                  <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <!--<input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="">-->
                    <%= f.email_field :email, :required => true, :class =>"form-control" %>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                 <!-- <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Password</label>-->
                 <%= f.label :password,:class => "col-sm-3 control-label"%>
                  <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <!--<input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="">-->
                    <%= f.password_field :password, :required => true, :class =>"form-control" %>
                  </div>
                </div>

               <% end %>

                <div class="form-group">
                 <!-- <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">&nbsp;</label>-->
                  <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <div class="btm-btn text-center">
                      <!--<button type="submit" class="btn-type">Create</button>-->
                      <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>


              <% end %>
            <!--</form>-->
          </div>
      </div>
```